# How to display with datetime condition in controller symfony2

Tags: symfony

i need to display the list of users where they registred after fixed date for example i need to replay the list of users after   2014-03-01 17:34:04 and the  the custom 's type in my table User is  datetime.
$user = $em->getRepository('UserUserBundle:user')->findBy();

Comment: What to you mean by *replay*?

Comment: It's still written *replay* in the title and in the question content.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of query to get the users after a chosen datetime (assuming that the field containing the datetime is named `datetime`):

```php
public function yourControllerAction()
{
    $dt = new \Datetime('2014-03-01 17:34:04');

    $qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UserUserBundle:user')
        ->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $users = $qb
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->gte('u.datetime',
                $qb->expr()->literal($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            )
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;

    return $this->render(
        'UserUserBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
        array(
            'users' => $users
        )
    );
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way by calling `literal()` but it works for me.

Then you'll have to display the users in your Twig template:

```twig
{% for user in users %}
    {% user.id %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```